Calculating $[K(t):K\left(\dfrac{t^2}{t-1}\right)]$ with $t$ a trascendental element over $K$.
I was asked in an excercise of my fields and Galois theory course to calculate the degree of the extension $K(t)/K\left(\dfrac{t^2}{t-1}\right)$ with $t$ a trascendental over $K$.
I started stuying all elements in $Aut(K(t)/K\left(\dfrac{t^2}{t-1}\right))$ (something also asked in the exercise) and found that they are exactly the ones such that $t\longrightarrow t$ and $t \longrightarrow \dfrac{t}{t-1}$ just by imposing the image of $t$, let it be $\zeta$, to satisfy $\dfrac{\zeta^2}{\zeta-1}=\dfrac{t^2}{t-1}$. So we have $|Aut(K(t)/K\left(\dfrac{t^2}{t-1}\right)|=2$.
For the degree of the extension, I tried finding $Irr(t,K\left(\dfrac{t^2}{t-1}\right))$, but haven't yet found it. Any idea?

Keep it simple. Let $s:=\frac{t^2}{t-1}$. Then, $t^2-st+s=0$. So...

So then the degree is less or equal to 2, but as it already was greater of equal to 2 because of the number of automorphisms, we have that it is exactly 2, and moreover, your polynomial is irreducible : )

Right, but what I meant by "Keep it simple" is that you didn't need to count the automorphisms. This polynomial directly gives the degree.

@AnneBauval, how do you know it is irreducible? Did you prove it has no roots?

I mean, I conclude that it was irreducible becuase of the automorphism argument, how do you know?

The roots are $t$ and $s-t$, which don't belong to $K(s)$.
